How can I make rollup dump the problematic code?
I'm getting this error from Rollup (via Vite)
vite v5.3.5 building for production...
src/foo.tsx (2:0): A comment

"/*#__NO_SIDE_EFFECTS__*/"

in "src/foo.tsx" contains an annotation that Rollup cannot interpret due to the position of the comment. The comment will be removed to avoid issues.

I would like to dump the code that Rollup is working on at this point, because it has already gone through a babel transformation. I think I should write an onLog handler, something like this:
      onLog: (level, log, handler) => {
        if (log.code === 'INVALID_ANNOTATION') {
          handler('error', log)
        } else {
          handler(level, log)
        }
      },

which is great and works to elevate the warning to an error, but I still can't SEE the contextual code for the error. Is there an easy way to convince Rollup to spit it out?

